# Do I need to know the distribution of the noise before I'm using Monte Carlo Sampling?

Tags: monte-carlo, particle-filter, sequential-monte-carlo

I'm going to use Particle Filter, which is a Monte Carlo Sampling.
My simple question is: Do I need to know the distribution of the noise before I'm using Monte Carlo Sampling?

Or can I just use a random distribution and let the weights tune in?
I don't really understand.

As I think I understand the Particle Filter/Monte Carlo Simulation. It want to find the most frequent measured state $x$ from a population $X$.
And do I really need a distribution for that? I can solve that by using some few for-loops and if-statements. It requries a lot of sampling > 1000 for each estimation, though.

Or is the distribution included because I should not measure so much for doing an estimation?

Comment: A particle filter targets a specific distribution so yes you do need to specify the distribution of all random elements in the model.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you. You can write an answer if you want so I can accept it. So if I have e.g poisson distribution, and the noise is chebychev distribution, then my particle filter will work poorly?